# Declaring a vector in a .h file, initialize in a .cpp file

Tags: c++, header, g++, stdvector

First of all, I know there are a lot of similar posts on here, but I've been looking through them in for a while and I am having trouble deciphering exactly what I need to do.  So on to my problem:  I am converting a Graph class I previously wrote in C to C++.  I am having trouble converting arrays to vectors due to how I initialize it.  If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome.  You can see that I started trying to convert the array char* color to vector color, but it didn't work and the G++ error message was long a cryptic.  I left out the #include statements, but I promise those aren't the problem.

**Graph.h**

```
using namespace std;
const int INF = INT_MAX;  
const int NIL = 0;

class Graph
{
    public:
    Graph(int n);
    Graph(ifstream& in);
    ~Graph(void);

    int getOrder();
    int getSize();
    int getSource();
    int getParent(int u);
    int getDist(int u);
    void getAdjacencyList(List* L, int u);

    void makeNull();
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int weight, int color);
    void addArc(int u, int v, int weight, int color);
    void BFS(int s, int c);
    void Prim(int s, int color);
    void printGraph();
    void printSpanningTree();
    private:
    bool colorApprover(int, bool ,bool , bool);
    void prepGraph(int n);
    int order;
    int size;
    int source;
    vector<char> color (16);
    int* distance;
    int* parent;
    List** edgeDist;
    List** edgeColor;
    List** adj;
};
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
//helper function to streamline the constructors
void Graph::prepGraph(int n){
    order = n;
    size = 0;
    source = NIL;
    //color (n + 1);//static_cast<char*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char)));
    distance = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    parent = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    adj = static_cast<List**>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
    edgeDist = static_cast<List**>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
    edgeColor = static_cast<List**>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(List*)));
    //discover = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    //finish = static_cast<int*>(calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int)));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        color[i] = 'w';
        distance[i] = INF;
        parent[i] = NIL;
        adj[i] = new List();
        edgeDist[i] = new List();
        edgeColor[i] = new List();
    }
}

Graph::Graph(int n){
    prepGraph(n);
}

Graph::Graph(ifstream& in){
int n;
in >> n;
prepGraph(n);
while(!in.eof()){
int i, j, weight, color;
in >> i;
        in >> j;
        in >> weight;
        in >> color;
        //increment values by 1 so they fit
        //into existing graph structure
        i += 1;
        j += 1;
        addEdge(i, j, weight, color);
        //cout << "added arc " << i << " " << j << endl;
    }       
}
```

I can't just do vector.push_back() because the rest of the code depends on the random access property of arrays, so they have to be ready to go here.  I'm too new to C++ and am still struggling with the syntax.

**EDIT:**
I guess I should have mentioned that this uses the edge list form of a graph.  The List is a class that I also wrote, which deals with nodes.  I just have all of these C arrays that I need converted to C++ vectors, and the syntax is killing me.  For example, the int* distance array should be a vector of ints, and the List** edgeDist and whatnot should be a vector of List*.  Its just initializing it in the Graph.cpp function Graph::prepGraph(int n) that I need help with.  The syntax is a little butchered, but I was trying to show what I am trying to do without totally ruining it.  In other words, those static_cast(calloc(whatever)) statements that I keep getting complaints over? Help me get rid of those.

Comment: don't use `malloc` or `calloc` in C++, unless you really know what you are doing. use `new` (and `delete`, not `free`)

Comment: Where exactly do you use `vector` here? I see only `list`s.

Comment: If the library works as expected in C, why not wrap it in extern C with a nice C++ wrapper?

Comment: `vector<char> color (16);` looks dubious.

Comment: So you started with good C (which is valid C++, unless it uses C++ reserved words), and made *one small change* which led to all the trouble? Or did you make many changes before attempting to compile it?

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code. I'll try to give you a start:

```
//helper function to streamline the constructors
typedef List<int> NodeList;
struct Node {
    char color;
    int distance;
    int parent;
    NodeList adj;
    NodeList edgeDist;
    NodeList edgeColor;

    Node() {
        color = 'w';
        distance = INF;
        parent = 0;
    }
}

class Graph
{ 
...
private:
    vector<Node> nodes;
...
}

void Graph::prepGraph(int n){
    order = n;
    size = 0;
    source = NIL;
    // nodes will be initialized implicitly
}
```